# Syntax issue is preventing mySQL results to show in HTML table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following script that should show the results of the MySQL query and populate the table below but it does the table comes out empty. I know there should be results shown, but I am unsure where the syntax issue is:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Part</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Ship_Date</th>
</tr>
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "
  SELECT t1.Country
     , t2.Part
     , t2.Description
     , Sum(t2.Quantity) AS Quantity
     , t1.ship_time
  FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table_Data2 t2 
    ON t1.CodeValue = t2.CodeValue
 WHERE t2.Part IN ('BB1234', 'BB-3454')
   AND t1.ship_time = Current_Date()
 GROUP 
    BY t1.Country
     , t2.Part
     , t2.Description
     , t1.ship_time;
";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["t1.Country"].
         "</td><td>".$row["t2.Part"]. 
         "</td><td>". $row["t2.description"]. 
         "</td><td>" .$row["t2.quantity"].
         "</td><td>". $row["t1.ship_time"]. "</td><td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else { 
    echo "0 results"; 
}
$conn->close();
?>
</table>
```

No error messages come up but I suspect the error may be when I do `echo "<tr><td>".$row["t1.Country"].` for each column

Comment: Is your error reporting on?

Comment: No error messages come up but I suspect the error may be when I do`echo "<tr><td>".$row["t1.Country"].` for each header

Comment: Is your database's name "dbname"? And your username is "username" and password is "password"?

Comment: I have removed the actual value for this example

Comment: Should I include the table name down here: `echo "<tr><td>".$row["t1.Country"].
     "</td><td>".$row["t2.Part"]. 
     "</td><td>". $row["t2.description"]. 
     "</td><td>" .$row["t2.quantity"].
     "</td><td>". $row["t1.ship_time"]. "</td><td>";
}`

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: I think this bit `"</td><td>";` should be `"</td></tr>";` or you are missing a closing `</tr>` tag

Comment: I have added the debugging code and it is not showing any errors

Comment: instead of t1.Country try 'Country' also keep in mind that table associations are case sensitive, so Country != country, you can just print_r( $row ) and see if values are appearing with the keys you're mentioning...

and also it should be $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Also the table does also say "0 results" so I believe it is the query not so much the table formatting \

Comment: try to write PHP and HTML separately : https://3v4l.org/knS0p:-

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row["t1.Country"]
```

You should replace like below:

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row["Country"]
```

And remove the t1 and t2 from all the other as well

Comment: You could also mention that the case is wrong on some of the other references like `Description` !== `description`